# "Do assessment of the problem" vs. "do an assessment of the problem"

Tags: difference, articles, indefinite-article

Would you tell me if using the article *a* adds anything to the sentence's meaning below?

> Before fixing it right away, I suggest we **do assessment** of the problem first.
>
> Before fixing it right away, I suggest we **do** **an** **assessment** of the problem first.

According to online dictionaries, assessment can be used both as a countable and uncountable noun, so I supposed both my sentences are correct. I'd like to know if there is any difference in meaning and if both are perfectly natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in your example sentence, the article is required.

The noun "assessment" is only uncountable when the meaning is *the general concept of assessment*. It's countable when referring to a specific instance of assessment or a particular assessment procedure to follow.

In your example, it's a specific instance of an assessment procedure.

Here's an example close to the meaning of your sentence without an article:

> Before fixing this right away, I suggest doing (some) assessment first.

This doesn't mean performing a specific procedure, but doing assessment in general, which may include several assessment procedures.

FWIW, the most natural way of wording your sentence is using the verb "assess":

> Before fixing it right away, I suggest we **assess** the problem first.

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot be an uncountable noun in the way that you're using it. Here is how it could be used as an uncountable noun:

> Assessment of taxes is usually done by a licensed professional.

When "assessment" is used as in your sentence, it can only be a countable noun:

> Before fixing it right away, I suggest we do an assessment of the problem first.